# Upload images to Imgur with Curl PHP

Tags: php, curl, imgur

```
<form action="php.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="img[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
foreach ($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpName) {
    if( !empty( $tmpName ) && is_uploaded_file( $tmpName ) )
    {
        $handle = fopen($tmpName, "r");
        $data = fread($handle, filesize($tmpName));
        $client_id = "d5f419ef9aedf16";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => base64_encode($data)));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));

        $reply = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        var_dump($info);
        if(curl_errno($ch))
            echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $reply = json_decode($reply);
        printf('<img height="180" src="%s" >', $reply->data->link);
    }
}
?>
```

I made this page, works perfectly on localhost but when I run it from my server it does not work, problem is I have no output at all, not even the curl_getinfo or errors. Dont know how to debug this since I can't get any info out of it.

Comment: check `$data` if it empty

Comment: Looks like if( !empty( $tmpName ) && is_uploaded_file( $tmpName ) ) is not met, that's why. On local is met but on the server is not.

Comment: So i tried to var_dump($_FILES); , if I try 3 or more images var_dump output is empty, for 1 or 2 images I get output: array(1) { ["img"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "1.png" [1]=> string(5) "2.png" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) } ["size"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) } } }

Comment: there should be permission problem that php cannot write to `/tmp` dir

Answer (score 1):

Thank you hans for the suggestions, you were right, it was not mandatory to use base64, not in V3 API, it was on the previous versions, not anymore. Now it's much faster. This is my final code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])){
    foreach ($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpName) {
        if( !empty( $tmpName ) && is_uploaded_file( $tmpName ) )
        {
            if ($handle = fopen($tmpName, "rb")) {
                $data = stream_get_contents($handle, filesize($tmpName));
                $client_id = "d5f619ef9aedf16";
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => $data));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
                $reply = curl_exec($ch);
                if(curl_errno($ch))
                    echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                $reply = json_decode($reply);
                $screens .= $reply->data->link . " ";
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why it was not uploading them images was upload_max_filesize and max_post_size, I've increased them and I had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

you do several things wrong.

this code: 
`foreach ($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpName) {`  will be executed even on GET requests, which contains no files, thus `$_FILES['img']` does not exist, and you get an `Undefined index: img` error. furthermore, on GET requests, this undefined index bug returns NULL to foreach, and when you tell foreach() to loop a NULL, it gives you this error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. the fact that you haven't already caught up on this, proves that you're not checking the php error logs. this is the first thing you should do, when debugging a malfunctioning php script. - to fix both of these, wrap the foreach in `if(!empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']){}` - next, find your PHP error logs, and read those error reports. (usually you can find it in phpinfo() under `error_log` - or in case its emptystring, its your web servers' error log, eg for nginx with an empty php error_log php setting, its in nginx's error log (like /var/log/nginx/error.log )

next issue, `$handle = fopen($tmpName, "r");` this will corrupt binary data (like images) on some systems (famously, windows), change it to `rb` for safely reading binary data (and image formats are binary)

next issue, you believe that fread()  reads as many bytes as you request it to read, that is incorrect. fread will read `UP TO` as many bytes as requested, but can stop for many reasons before it has read the requested number of bytes. you'll either have to loop calling fread until it has read all the bytes, or better yet, use stream_get_contents, which will essentially do that fread() loop for you.

next issue, this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));` is completely unnecessary, PHP's STDERR is libcurl's default STDERR anyway.

next issue, you don't fclose() $handle. this is ok for short running scripts (becuase the OS fclose() it for you when the script finishes), but the bigger your code grows, the longer the resource leak will be there, its a good programming habit to always close it, so do that.

next issue, i can't believe imgur actually wants a base64 encoded copy of the image, that is such a cpu & bandwidth & ram waste... the POST encoding they're using, `multipart/form-data` is fully binary safe, so there's no reason to base64 encode it... are you sure they want it base64 encoded? you AND them can save about 33% bandwidth by NOT using base64 encoding here.

given all the things you are doing wrong with the file operations, it'd be better to use the `file_get_contents` function - it reads the entire file, it opens the file in binary read mode (as opposed to your code, where you open it in TEXT mode, potentially corrupting the image as you read it), and it reads the entire file, not just the chunk of it that the first fread() call will read (which, if you're lucky, is the entire file, but if you're not lucky, is just the first chunk of it), and it does fclose() for you (which you forget to do)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use imgur php sdk and simple implement it with below code:

```
require_once APPPATH."/third_party/imgur/vendor/autoload.php";


    $pathToFile = '../path/to/file.jpg';
    $imageData = [
        'image' => $pathToFile,
        'type'  => 'file',
    ];

    $client->api('image')->upload($imageData);
```